# Update from select on multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a bit rusty with Oracle statements - Im trying to create an update statement that makes the 
a.col2 'Y'. The col3 and col4 contains the same data but column names are different (a lot of columns in both tables). 
Here is my select statement that identifies all entries:

```
select a.col1, b.col1, a.col2, b.col2, a.col3, b.col4 from 
table1 a, table2 b
 where a.col1 = 'XX'
 and a.col1 = b.col1
 and b.col5 = 'XX'
 and a.col3 = b.col4
 and a.col2 = b.col2
 and a.col2 = 'X'
 and a.col3 like 'XX%'
```

This will not work, right (?):

```
 update table1 a, table2 b
 set a.col1 = 'Y'
 where a.col1 = 'XX'
 and a.col1 = b.col1
 and b.col5 = 'XX'
 and a.col3 = b.col4
 and a.col2 = b.col2
 and a.col2 = 'X'
 and a.col3 like 'XX%'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want `exists`:

```
update table1 a
     set a.col1 = 'Y'
     where a.col1 = 'XX' and
           a.col2 = 'X' and
           a.col3 like 'XX%' and
           exists (select 1
                   from table2 b
                   where a.col1 = b.col1 and
                         b.col5 = 'XX' and
                         a.col3 = b.col4 and
                         a.col2 = b.col2
                  );
```